# Unable to deselect ttk checkbuttons (initialised by my own class) when another one of my classes creates it

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, python-class

This is a follow-up question from this: [Setting ttk checkbutton IntVar to 0, but ttk checkbutton does not deselect. .?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70677367/setting-ttk-checkbutton-intvar-to-0-but-ttk-checkbutton-does-not-deselect)

Thanks to the help from @acw1668, I was able to initialise deselected checkbuttons when I created them from `__main__`. However, when I create my checkbuttons object via a different class, the checkbuttons do not deselect. Here is what I mean:

This is my module `Widgets`:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class Checkbuttons():
    def __init__(self,parent,list_of_values,column,row,**kwargs):
        #Converts list into dictionary
        self.values = {}
        for value in list_of_values:
            self.values[value] = tk.IntVar()
        column_counter = column
        row_counter = row
        for tag in list(self.values):
            Checkbutton(parent,tag,self.values[tag],column_counter,row_counter,width=15)
            self.values[tag].set(0)
            row_counter += 1

class Checkbutton(ttk.Checkbutton):
    def __init__(self,parent,text,variable,column,row,search=True,**kwargs):
        kwargs['text'] = text
        kwargs['variable'] = variable
        super().__init__(parent,**kwargs)
        self.grid(column=column,row=row)
```

Now in my main program when I use this class like this:

```
import Widgets
import tkinter as tk

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    my_list = ['e-book epub','e-book PDF','Paperback','Hardcover','Audiobook MP3','Audible','Kindle']
    a = Widgets.Checkbuttons(root,my_list,1,1)
    root.mainloop()
```

then it works as expected (all the checkbuttons are deselected). But when I use a class (which generates a frame) to create the checkbuttons, it does not work:

```
import Widgets
import tkinter as tk

class Frame1(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,column,row,columnspan=None,rowspan=None,**kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        super().__init__(parent,**kwargs)
        self.grid(column=column,row=row,columnspan=columnspan,rowspan=rowspan)
        my_list = ['e-book epub','e-book PDF','Paperback','Hardcover','Audiobook MP3','Audible','Kindle']
        a = Widgets.Checkbuttons(self,my_list,1,1)        

class App():
    def __init__(self,parent):
        a = Frame1(parent,1,4,columnspan=6)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    App(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

I think the problem is in the class which creates the frame, but I do not know how to isolate the problem or how to debug. I am creating instances of all the classes, so I don't think it is getting garbage collected. Will greatly appreciate any help as to why the checkbuttons do not deselect.

---

Edit: I also tried changing this in my `class Checkbuttons:`

```
Checkbutton(parent,tag,self.values[tag],column_counter,row_counter,width=15)
```

to

```
a = Checkbutton(parent,tag,self.values[tag],column_counter,row_counter,width=15)
```

but that also does not help.

Comment: Why are there 2 `Checkbuttons` defined? This isnt the proper way to create a custom widget

Comment: It is the same issue as `a` is a local variable inside `Frame1.__init__()`, it will be garbage collected after the function exits.  Change `a` to instance variable `self.a`.

Comment: Thanks @acw1668. I clearly don't understand instance variables correctly and will do more research. Thanks for your help :)